# The touchpad does not work after installing ubuntu 20.04 on an hp laptop

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, synaptics

Notebook: HP Pavilion 15-ec1058ur 22P97EA (AMD Ryzen 5 4600H 3.0GHz/16384Mb/512Gb SSD/nVidia GeForce GTX 1650 4096Mb)

Hello, during the installation, the touchpad worked completely, after installation, it stopped working at all. I found a solution on the internet to make changes to /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

After that, the touchpad is working, but the two-finger scroll doesn't work. Please help me solve this problem.

[Mouse settings before install ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbcfz.jpg)

[Mouse settings installed ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbD0C.png)

Output xinput before installation ubuntu

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0718:00 04F3:30FD Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0718:00 04F3:30FD Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output xinput in installed ubuntu

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Videos: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FTFrBdrQcP84pLk5tbAIA68viO78TidL?usp=sharing

Ubuntu_live.mp4 - Running ubuntu from a flash drive in live mode BEFORE installation, the touchpad works

Ubuntu_installed.mp4 - Ubuntu after installation, the touchpad only works after changing to /etc/default/grub, the scroll does not work

PS: sorry my bad english